# What about the convergence of these series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

1. $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \arctan \frac{1}{2n + 1} $$
2. $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan ( \log n ) ) $$
3. $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin ( n \pi + \frac{1}{\log n } ) $$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the matter? What have you tried?

Comment: and what about the whether?

Comment: OK, Saaqib, for the first one there are two ways (that come into my mind): Ratio test or integral test. Give it a try.

Comment: For the second one, look at the difference between pi/2 and arctanx. That difference is arguably smaller than the difference between pi/2 and arctan(lnx), do you know why? Now through the integral test and a bit of L'Hospital it can be shown that the first integral is divergent, so by comparison the second one has to be divergent too.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**

1. $$\arctan x\sim_0 x$$
2. $$\arctan x=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\frac 1 x\right),\quad x>0$$
3. $$\sin(n\pi+x)=(-1)^n\sin x$$